# Getting longitude and latitude from a GraphicsLayer using ArcGIS API for JavaScript ( 3.32 )

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

**Update : I have to position a button at the bottom of a layer, i try with Point, fullExtent and xyToLngLat.**

**but the result seems offset sometime.**

---

I have a hard time getting longitude & latitude from a GraphicsLayer and don't find anything in the documentation for that.

API 3.x.x
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/

GraphicsLayer
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html

```
require([
        "esri/map",
        "dojo/on",
        "esri/arcgis/utils",
        "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, on, arcgisUtils, webMercatorUtils) {
        arcgisUtils
            .createMap("mapID...", "map", {
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: 11
                }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                map = response.map;
                map.setInfoWindowOnClick(true);
                map.disableScrollWheelZoom();
                esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomDuration = 1000;

                let layer = map.getLayer('1233_..._layer');
                // How to get longitude latitude ?


let point = Point({
    x: layer.fullExtent.xmin,
    y: layer.fullExtent.ymin,
    spatialReference: map.spatialReference
})

let positionButton = esri.geometry.xyToLngLat(point.x, point.y);
//  Result seems off sometime.

            });
    });
});
```

Comment: what would be the latitude/longitude of a layer?, what are you trying to obtain? the full extent coordinates?

Comment: @cabesuon I have to position a button at the bottom of a layer, i try with Point, fullExtent and xyToLngLat.

but the result seems offset sometime.

Comment: when you say button is a real button?, you want to add a button to a specific location of the map? not screen? just curious. Can you add a screenshot of the button and why you think it is off. BTW sorry for the delay in the response.